# Change Garbage Collection Method

Tags: java-8, garbage-collection, java-11

We upgraded from Java 8 to Java 11 and now when our program that uses Java runs, it seems to run out of memory, which makes me think something is wrong with garbage collection.

I have changed the values below

```
"-Xms512m" "-Xmx512m"
```

To these values:

```
"-Xms512m" "-Xmx4096m"
```

But this does not seem to help. I would like to try forcing Java-11 to use the same default Garbage Collection method as Java-8, since everything worked fine there.

Which file do I need to edit in order to force a certain Garbage Collection to be used? I would like Java-11 to use `Parallel/Throughput GC`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 4096m = 4GB of memory

Comment: Start with your assumption: what makes you think you have a Garbage Collect problem? Perhaps you have an undiagnosed memory leak in your code. Make sure you're chasing the right shadow.

Comment: Changing the garbage collector won't cure your memory leak. It might however expose it more quickly, or more slowly.

Comment: I suspect garbage collection because we never had this problem under the old version of Java we were using, Java 8, only Java 11.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Java 11 to use the parallel / throughput collector by giving the jvm option `-XX:+UseParallelGC` This implicitly enables `UseParallelOldGC` as well.

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/available-collectors.html ... and the Java manual entry.

---

However I agree with the comments.  I / we suspect that the GC used is NOT the REAL cause of your problems.  Rather, I suspect that you have a memory leak or a memory management problem, and it becomes apparent more quickly with G1GC than with ParallelGC.

The proper solution will be to investigate the underlying cause of the problem.  Fiddling with the GC options is a [band aid solution](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/band-aid-solution).  Even if the fix works now, you are liable to run into the problems again in the future; e.g. if your input datasets gets bigger.

Comment: (I couldn't find a suitable dup for this question.  If someone can find one, please let me know.)